# Membership Renewal Reminders not Sending for Upgraded Memberships

Tags: scheduled-reminders

So we have a situation where someone had Membership A in 2016, and Bought Membership B in 2018 so the Membership type upgraded.

```
Member Since: March 9th, 2016   
Start Date: February 26th, 2018 
End Date: February 25th, 2022 (they bought 4 terms)
```

We then have a scheduled reminder that is supposed to send 1 day after the Membership Join Date.

What we are observing, is anyone who had a prior membership or an older "Member Since" date is not receiving the email the next day, whereas the completely new Members who are starting their first membership are.

How do we resolve this? Perhaps I midjudged what "Membership Join Date" meant in scheduled reminders?

CiviCRM 4.7.30 / Drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "join date" is the "Member Since" date; it's a bit odd that there's no option to select "Membership Start Date" in Scheduled Reminders.  Perhaps someone else could explain what I'm missing.

You could work around this via CiviRules, or adding the Start Date to the Scheduled Reminders would be simple.  It's SO simple that I'm sure there's a case I'm not thinking of why that's not desirable...

Also - you can create a reminder on the "Member Renewal" activity type instead.

Comment: Why can't we just add "Start Date" in Scheduled Reminders? Can anyone weigh in on this? I will use Rules

Comment: I made the reminder based on the Member Signup/Renewal Activity Type of "Completed" and then selected a smart group of the membership type(s) I wanted to send to who had not opted out of mailings

Answer (score 2):

As of CiviCRM 5.3.0, "Membership Start Date" is available as an option for basing your Scheduled Reminders off of.