# {membership.type} token not being filled out/sent in activity based scheduled reminders

Tags: tokens, scheduled-reminders

Based on the results of this question ([Membership Renewal Reminders not Sending for Upgraded Memberships](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24232/membership-renewal-reminders-not-sending-for-upgraded-memberships/24233#24233)) we switched our Scheduled Reminders to be activity based.

Now, the {membership.type} token shows up blank in the scheduled emails. How can we fix this?

We tried using https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken but the token for 'Latest Membership Type' seems to pick a membership based on the end date, and because we have two memberships present on some records (connected to two orgs), this will not always produce the correct token.

Thanks for your help!

CiviCRM 4.7.30 / Drupal 7

Comment: My understanding is the core token for membership will only get filled when it is in a 'membership context' and hence won't work in the Activity context. Shame our civitoken extension doesn't work for your use case. I expect this will require some development and hopefully someone points you in the right direction

Comment: petednz would it be possible to modify https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken/blob/master/tokens/latestcurrentmembership.inc to exclude one membership type from the 'latest' list? if so, it would work

Comment: sounds reasonable to me at a conceptual (non-code) level for your specific situation. Sing out if you want some paid support to achieve this if you need and can't get help here or on Chat.